# Expand two lines of a triangle/ Scale a line only at one side

Tags: transforms, lines

[image]

So is there away to scale the upper yellow line to the lower yellow line so the triangle scales along the two lines left and right in red?

And is it possible to scale the blue line only at one side in the direction which the line is currently facing (add the pink part)?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Select pyramid's apical vertex, snap cursor to selected, set pivot point to cursor; select edge and scale.

Comment: I tried your way but I'm not sure if I just did it wrong, or it just  doesn't works.

Comment: But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is "edge slide". Make sure to uncheck clamp:

[image]

Comment: the shortcut to disable clamp is C (or keep pressing Alt)

Comment: thank you! i love shortcuts ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot that was exactly what I was looking for.